# Tar - Transform stdin without extracting

Tags: tar, git

I am attempting to transform the paths of a tar file coming from standard input without having to extract the tar first.

This is an apparent duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108623/transform-a-tar-archives-paths-without-extracting-it), I am looking for a solution that can be accomplished without having to extract in order to simplify my script, so I do not care if the performance is the same as extracting.

**Use Case:**

I am creating a tar from git archive, and piping the result to an ssh process that will run on another machine that does not have the --transform option for tar. I will therefore need to transform before sending it over to ssh. I could always extract to a temporary directory, and then recreate another tar with the transform, but I am looking for a one-line solution to temporarily pop into an existing script.

Comment: If you open a tar file in a text editor you will see that the paths are part of the structure.  You will probably need to parse the entire tar structure to accomplish what you want in a safe way (without changing file content that may contain text that looks like a path for example).

Comment: There's an old script named `tarcust` that can rename files like that in a pipe, maybe you can still find it around.  Otherwise, the Perl module `Archive::Tar` can also do that, but you'll have to write some code.

Comment: Workaround that can possibly solve your underlying issue: if that other machine with the more traditional tar happens to have the pax program, pax can handle tar files and transform file names.